# Matching documents with two values in nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So, I have the following structure in some documents:

```
{
  "Group": [
    {
      "data": {
        "field1": "VALUE1",
        "otherfield": "XXXX"
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "field1": "VALUE2",
        "otherfield": "YYYYY"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The size of the `Group` array can be either 0, 1 or 2 in size. What I need to to is match the documents which contains both of `VALUE1` and `VALUE2` for `field1`. Couldn't find a suitable answer in here for this specific case.

I tried using `$elemMatch` but it will not work to bring only documents with both values. That is, it will work like an `or` not `and`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) array query operator with dot notation for this:

```
db.test.find({'Group.data.field1': {$all: ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2']}})
```

> The `$all` operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements.